# Windows Visual Studio 2003 support

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2003

I have an old application developed in  Microsoft Visual studio 2003. I have received a change request to modify few functionalities.
Please let me know the link to download Visual Studio 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are MSDN subscriber you can not obtain the Visual Studio 2003. See [this Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291372%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for MSDN Subscribers

Take a look at [Development Tools and Languages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa187916.aspx) too.

Answer (score 0):

I assume VS 2003 is [not supported](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5f7e875f-79df-45e2-ad36-32ea8f9a7bc9/visual-studio-net-2003-end-of-support) and maybe also not available for purchase anymore. For further information have a look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c2286b91-096b-4f36-9880-69ac3fa7d309/download-visual-studio-2003).

Answer (score 0):

As of end of 2019 MS still provides downloads for free SDK:

- [Windows® Server 2003 SP1 Platform SDK exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12261)
- [Windows® Server 2003 SP1 Platform SDK ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15656)